# A conditional probability question

Tags: probability

The question is:

There are two box, the first one contains n red balls, and the second one contains m balls with only one red ball and otherwise blue, (m, n>2). Now we randomly select one box, then choose two balls in turn without replacement.

(1). Find out the probability p with which the ball chosen first is red

(2). Under the condition in which the first ball is red, calculate the probability q with which the second ball is also red.

Evidently,

```
                               p = (m+1)/2m
```

However, the probability q which I calculated is

```
                               p = m/(m+1)
```

is wrong as the author said it's a common error. Correct answer the author gave is

```
                                q = 1/2
```

I read the comment given by the author. Let Ai(i=1,2) denotes the event of (i)th box being selected, C denotes the event the ball chosen is red. The author said that

```
                             P(A1) = 1/2
                             P(A2) = 1/2
                             P(C|A1) = 1
                             P(C|A2) = 0
```

Thus,

```
                       q = P(C) = 1*1/2 + 0*1/2
```

And the wrong algorithm I used (Bi denotes the event that (i)th ball chosen is red)

```
                             q = P(B2|B1)
```

The author pointed out that it cannot guarantee that the partitioned B1 be the same in the numerator and denominator if we continue this method.

However, I thought this question in another way. If the first ball chosen is red, the probability of the selected box is first one or second one will change as I think.

Therefor, I calculated the probability

```
                              P(A1|B1) = m/(m+1)
                              P(A2|B1) = 1/(m+1)
```

Thus, I think that the probability of the second ball chosen being red is

```
                           q=1*m/(m+1) + 0*1/m+1
```

which is the same as my precedent wrong answer.

**My question is what's the fallacy of my reasoning. And could you show me  a restricted mathematical calculation of the answer not just verbal reasoning?**

Because question is hard to google, I'm sorry for duplicating. If there are a similar question. Please give me a pointer. Thank you!

English is not my native language, if I said something which is inaccurate . Please point me out. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is the third question you asked where you got answers to the question, but did not accept them. That's very rude of you.

Comment: @5xum Sorry for that, I didn't know I the accept thing before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$-th box is chosen, $B$ and $C$ be the event that the $1$st and $2$nd ball is red respectively.

First, a side issue here is that the author has oppressed the conditional notation, so the probability $P$ used in the comment is different from the 1st part which will easily cause confusion. What he mean is

$$ P(C|A_1, B) = 1, P(C|A_2, B) = 0$$

Note that without the information that the $1$st ball is red, we have
$$ P(C|A_2) = P(B|A_2) = \frac {1} {m}$$

Now the main issue is how do you interpret $q$ - what is the meaning of "Under the condition in which the first ball is red"

The author mean that
$$ q = P(B \cap C) = P(B \cap C|A_1)P(A_1) + P(B \cap C|A_2)P(A_2) = \frac {1} {2} $$

But you interpret as

$$ q = P(C|B) = \frac {P(B \cap C)} {P(C)} = \frac {1} {2} \times \frac {2m} {m+1} = \frac {m} {m+1}$$

So this cause the difference. The lexical ambiguity here is not a big issue in your study - as long as you know the math it is ok. IMHO I will vote for your answer.

Comment: BGM, thank you for your answer! Do you mean that the "condition" the author used is not the kind of we-knew-it kind of condition, it's the condition that we should follow? In others words, first chosen ball being red it also belongs to the event in the experiment.

Comment: As said it is just wordings problem which does not worth any further effort to try to guess the author intention. For me I will have the same guess as you.

Answer (score 1):

$P(R,R) = P(B1).P(2nd Red/1st Red) + P(B2).P(2nd Red/1st Red) = \frac{1}{2}.1 + \frac{1}{2}.0 = \frac{1}{2}$
 Your answer is incorrect because, the first selection  is again amongst the boxes and then two balls, thus, the first box contains all red and hence P(2nd is Red/1st is Red in Box1) = 1 and in the other box P(2nd is Red /1st is Red in Box 2) = 0(due to without replacement condition)

Did you not use the above logic for the first part.

$P(R) = P(box 1) . P(red/Box 1) + P(box 2).P(red/Box 2) = \frac{1}{2}.1 + \frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{m}$.